# Clojure - map function

Tags: clojure

As we know, `(map f [a b c])` is equivalent to `[(f a) (f b) (f c)]`.

My question is: The evaluation result of `(map #(- (int %) (int \0)) "1234")` is `(1 2 3 4)`, why does it return the results of applying `#(- (int %) (int \0))` to every digits of "1234", rather than the string "1234" as a whole? How should I understand this code example?

Comment: This has bitten me quite often

Comment: One qualification: The result of `(map f [a b c])` isn't exactly the same as the result of `[(f a) (f b) (f c)]`, since `map` returns a lazy sequence rather than a vector.  I think it's correct to say that the result of `(map f [a b c])` is the same as the result of `(lazy-seq [(f a) (f b) (f c)])`, and that result of `(vec (map f [a b c]))` is the same as the result of `[(f a) (f b) (f c)]`.  (If I'm wrong about some details, more knowledgeable people will hopefully correct me.)

Comment: You don't need `map` if you just want to call a function using a single argument. If that's what you want, then don't use `map`: `(#(- (int %) (int \0)) "1234")`

Comment: @DaoWen Your code produces `ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Character ...` - surely not what's intended.

Comment: @Thumbnail - Ha, you're right, thanks. You would need to use `Integer/parseInt` to convert the string to an int instead of the `int` "cast" that works for chars. The point is that I don't really understand the OP's question—*if you just want to apply the function to the string (not the individual characters), why don't you just call it directly rather than using `map`?* Apparently I'm missing something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` calls `seq` on all arguments after the first. `seq` turns a string into a sequence of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Clojure can treat a string as a sequence - of characters. This is useful because you can:

- map things over the string
- partition the string
- get locations by index
- do everything else sequences do.

It's perhaps a bit annoying having to remember to put the resulting sequence back into a string by wrapping the sequence manipulating expression in a call to `str`.

Comment: it may make sense to merge our answers into yours, since yours is more complete anyway - perhaps making it clear that it is specifically `map` which calls seq on args, and showing `(apply str (map f string))` as the canonical way to get a string back out the other side.

Comment: I value the simplicity, elegance, and implicit generality of your answer, @noisesmith, as well as Arthur Ulfeldt's discussion of the ramifications and purpose of `map`'s behavior.